# Why does one burner on my gas stove release no gas, but the rest work fine?

Tags: gas, stove

I have a thermador gas stovetop, and today it just stopped releasing gas to a single burner.  When I say it stopped, I mean on any other burner I can audibly hear gas released before ignition, but on this one, there is *no* sound, nothing, and it obviously doesn't ignite.

I have cleaned out the holes on the top piece, but it's pointless, because no gas at all is being released.  Yet, all other burners work fine.

I wondered if each burner has a safety built in, that needs to be reset somehow, that prevents gas from coming out if it previously couldn't ignite (I did find a small piece of debris by the igniter at the beginning, so it's possible it failed a few times when someone used it earlier).  I have unplugged the stove and plugged it back in, but I see no reset button or anything.

Comment: The first thing you should do is contact thermador. https://www.thermador.com/us/support/customer-care  1-800-735-4328

Comment: I agree contacting the MFG may be best it could be a safety or some moisture / debris stuck in the valve.

Comment: There might be some blockage down in the pipes that go between the gas line and the burner. I would also contact the manufacturer, because taking this apart isn't exactly a straightforward procedure.

Comment: Yeah, call a "gas appliance mechanic" or whatever they are called if you goof a repair on this stuff you, or someone else you love, can wind up dead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The control chip at the knob had burned out.